# In a hash table, are keys stored with their corresponding values?

Tags: hashtable

As an example, I'm writing a hash table that has names as keys and telephone numbers as data. Should it be a table of names combined with numbers (i.e. a table of structs) or just a table of just the numbers? Because if you're looking up someone's telephone number, you already know their name, so I don't see the point of storing the name with the number.

Answer (score 1):

There are some general suggestions for some problems you are facing on:

- If you want to quickly look up data based on some key, like in a dictionary or a 
  **phone-book, use a map**.
- If the values are unique, have operator < defined, and you want quick look-ups, use 
  a set.
- If you repeatedly want the largest value, use a priority_queue.
- If you want to quickly add values but you don't need to access them often, use a list.
- If you want to quickly access values at a specific position, use a vector.

Back to your question a HashTable is a table implementation with constant time access. Like a map, you can store key-value pair associations in the hash table. However, hash tables don’t store the data in sorted order. A hash table is implemented with a array at the top level. Each key is mapped to a slot in the array by a hash function. But Sometimes it useful to combine containers to get the best advantages of each container. Like your phone-book.

For instance, suppose we want to look up records based on more than one key type.

```
John-Romero 
5673-67854

Alice-Nice
3452-878
```

We want to be able to look up the records by entering their name or phonenumber.  So we want 2 search keys for each record. (We assume all keys are unique.)  But a map only lets us have only one key per record, One solution is to create a master list of the records.  For each key type, create a map that contains iterators pointing to the record in the phone-book.

To make record insertion O(1), a list would be good for the phone-book.

> Imagine a phonebook with 50,000 name/number pairings. Each number is a
>   10 digit number. We need to create a data structure to lookup the name
>   matching a particular phone number. Ideally, name lookup should be
>   O(1) time expected, and the caller ID system should use O(n) memory (n
>   = 50,000).

```
list<Record> phone_book;
```

To make look-ups O(1), a map would be best for the keys.

```
map<string, list<Record>::iterator> names;
map<int, list<Record>::iterator> phones;
```

We can print a record by dereferencing the iterator:

```
cout << *names["John-Romero"];
```

here is a sample program in Java with a single key

```
import java.util.*;
public class PhoneBook {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* instantiate a Hashtable Object*/
        Hashtable dict = new Hashtable();
        /* it is just an iterator */
        Enumeration iterator;
        /* the temporary key value*/
        String tempKey;
        /* here we put some key and value */
        dict.put("Zahurul Islam",new Long(898989));
        dict.put("Naushad Uzzaman", new Long(676767));
        dict.put("Asif Iqbal", new Long(565656));
        dict.put("Mr.Pavel", new Long(232323));
        dict.put("Marzy Rahman",new Long(343434));
        dict.put("Mehedi Al mamun",new Long(234324));

        /* here we traverse the dict */
        iterator = dict.keys();
        while (iterator.hasMoreElements()) {
            Object key = iterator.nextElement();
            System.out.println("Name: "+ key +" Phone Number: "+ dict.get(key));
        }

        /* this is temporay key, if this is exist we just change the value
         * other wise we put the pair(key,value)  */
        tempKey = "Zahurul Islam";
        if(!dict.containsKey(tempKey)) {
            System.out.println("No such Name in this phone Book");
        } else {
            Long phoneNumber = (Long) dict.get(tempKey);
            long phNum = phoneNumber.longValue();
            System.out.println(phNum+ " This Phone Number of "+ tempKey + " is changed ");
            dict.put(tempKey, new Long(121212));
        }

        System.out.println("\nUpdated Phone book\n");
        iterator = dict.keys();
        while (iterator.hasMoreElements()) {
            Object key = iterator.nextElement();
            System.out.println("Name: "+ key +" Phone Number: "+ dict.get(key));
        }



    }

}
```

And here is other with 2-keys

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.*;

/************************************************************************************
 * This class provides hash maps that use the hashing with separate chaining algorithm.
 * A hash table is created that is an array of buckets.  It restricts the number of
 * slots per bucket to one (just one key-value pair), but could easily be extended
 * to support multiple key-value pairs per bucket.
 */
public class HashSC <K, V>
       extends AbstractMap <K, V>
       implements Serializable, Cloneable, Map <K, V>
{
    /********************************************************************************
     * This inner class defines buckets that are stored in the hash table.
     */
    private class Bucket
    {
        K      key;       // alt. use K [] instead of K
        V      value;     // alt. use V [] instead of V
        Bucket next;
        Bucket (K k, V v, Bucket n) { key = k; value = v; next = n; }
    } // Bucket inner class

    /** The array of buckets making up the hash table.
     */
    private final Bucket [] hTable;

    /** The size of the hash table (number of home buckets)
     */
    private final int size;

    /** Counter for the number buckets accessed (for performance testing)
     */
    private int count = 0;

    /********************************************************************************
     * Construct a hash table that uses separate chaining.
     * @param cap  the capacity of the hash table
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public HashSC (int cap)
    {
        hTable = (Bucket []) Array.newInstance (Bucket.class, size = cap);
    } // HashSC

    /********************************************************************************
     * Return a set view of map containing all the entries as pairs of keys and values.
     * @return  the set view of the map
     */
    public Set <Map.Entry <K, V>> entrySet ()
    {
        Set <Map.Entry <K, V>> enSet = new HashSet <> ();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (Bucket b = hTable [i]; b != null; b = b.next) {
                enSet.add (new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry <K, V> (b.key, b.value));
            } // for
        } // for

        return enSet;
    } // entrySet

    /********************************************************************************
     * Given the key, look up the value in the hash table.
     * @param key  the key used for look up
     * @return  the value associated with the key
     */
    public V get (Object key)
    {
        int i = h (key);
        for (Bucket b = hTable [i]; b != null; b = b.next) {
            count++;
            if (b.key.equals (key)) return b.value;
        } // for
        return null;
    } // get

    /********************************************************************************
     * Put the key-value pair in the hash table.
     * @param key    the key to insert
     * @param value  the value to insert
     * @return  null (not the previous value)
     */
    public V put (K key, V value)
    {
        int i = h (key);
        hTable [i] = new Bucket (key, value, hTable [i]);
        return null;
    } // put

    /********************************************************************************
     * Return the size (number of home buckets) in the hash table. 
     * @return  the size of the hash table
     */
    public int size ()
    {
        return size;
    } // size

    /********************************************************************************
     * Print the hash table.
     */
    private void print ()
    {
        out.println ("Hash Table (hashing with separate chaining)");
        out.println ("-------------------------------------------");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            out.print (i + ":\t");
            boolean notFirst = false;
            for (Bucket b = hTable [i]; b != null; b = b.next) {
                if (notFirst) out.print ("--> ");
                out.print ("[ " + b.key + " ]\t");
                notFirst = true;
            } // for
            out.println ();
        } // for
        out.println ("-------------------------------------------");
    } // print

    /********************************************************************************
     * Hash the key using the hash function.
     * @param key  the key to hash
     * @return  the location of the bucket chain containing the key-value pair
     */
    private int h (Object key)
    {
        return key.hashCode () % size;
    } // h

    /********************************************************************************
     * The main method used for testing.
     * @param  the command-line arguments (args [0] gives number of keys to insert)
     */
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        HashSC <Integer, Integer> ht_i = new HashSC <> (11);
        HashSC <String, Integer>  ht_s = new HashSC <> (11);
        int nKeys = 30;
        if (args.length == 1) nKeys = Integer.valueOf (args [0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < nKeys; i += 2) {
            ht_i.put (i, i * i);
            ht_s.put ("s" + i, i * i);
        } // for
        ht_i.print ();
        ht_s.print ();
        for (int i = 0; i < nKeys; i++) {
            out.println ("key = " + i + "  value = " + ht_i.get (i));
            out.println ("key = s" + i + " value = " + ht_s.get ("s" + i));
        } // for
        out.println ("-------------------------------------------");
        out.println ("Average number of buckets accessed = " + ht_i.count / (double) nKeys);
        out.println ("Average number of buckets accessed = " + ht_s.count / (double) nKeys);
    } // main

} // HashSC class
```

I think you can compare the efficiency of both solutions (the last code needs to be modified to be a phone-book) so you can decide which better suits your needs.